# Rendered form is not posting data

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, doctrine

I use a single page template in my symfony website which has a contact form section.

I have rendered my contact action(appbundle:contact:new) to my homepage.The ContactController is auto generated by doctrine CRUD.

It displays the form perfectly. But it doesn't perform any action. Did i miss anything?

**My view**

```
{% block header %}{% include'header.html.twig' %}{% endblock %}
{% block nav %}{% include'nav.html.twig' %}{% endblock %}
{% block mainHeader %}{% include'mainHeader.html.twig' %}{% endblock %}
{% block body %} {% endblock %}
{% block projetCategories %}{% include'projetCategories.html.twig' %}{% endblock %}
{% block projets %}{% include'projets.html.twig' %}{% endblock %}
{#{% block contact %}{{ render(controller('BlogBundle:Contact:new')) }}{% endblock %}#}
{% block contact %}{% include':contact:new.html.twig' %}{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}{% include'footer.html.twig' %}{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}{% include'javascript.html.twig' %}{% endblock %}
```

**My Controller**

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $contact = new Contact();
    $form = $this->createForm('BlogBundle\Form\ContactType', $contact);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        //$contactData = [$form->getValue('nom'), $form->getValue('prenom'),$form->getValue('email'), $form->getValue('sujet'), $form->getValue('message')];
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($contact);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('blog_homepage', array('id' => $contact->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('contact/new.html.twig', array(
        'contact' => $contact,
        'contactForm' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
}
```

**My Model**

```
class Contact {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
public $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $prenom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $sujet;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $message;
```

My new.html.twig

```
<div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
                {{ form_start(contactForm) }}
                {{ form_widget(contactForm) }}
                <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
                {{ form_end(contactForm) }}
```

**My form**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('nom', TextType::class, array('label'=>false, 'attr'=>array(
            'class'=>'form-control',
            'placeholder'=>'Nom*',
            'style'=>"margin-bottom:5px;"
            )));
        $builder->add('prenom', TextType::class, array('label'=>false, 'attr'=>array(
            'class'=>'form-control',
            'placeholder'=>'Prénom*',
            'style'=>"margin-bottom:5px;"
            )));
        $builder->add('email', EmailType::class, array('label'=>false, 'attr'=>array(
            'class'=>'form-control',
            'placeholder'=>'Email*',
            'style'=>"margin-bottom:5px;"
            )));
        $builder->add('sujet', ChoiceType::class, array( 'label'=>false,
            'choices' => array(
                'Quel sujet?'=> false, 
                '1'=>'1', 
                '2'=>'2', 
                '3'=>'3', 
            ),
            'choices_as_values' => true,
            'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control','style'=>"margin-bottom:5px;"),
            'choice_attr' => function($val, $key, $index) {
                // adds a class like attending_yes, attending_no, etc
                return ['class' => strtolower($key)];
            },
        ));
        $builder->add('message', TextareaType::class, array('label'=>false, 'attr'=>array(
            'class'=>'form-control',
            'placeholder'=>'Message*',
            'style'=>"margin-bottom:5px;",
            'cols'=>50,
            'rows'=>10
        )));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'BlogBundle\Entity\Contact'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'blogbundle_contact';
    }
```

The error message after the source code modification

```
Variable "contactForm" does not exist.
```

Comment: you render the template in which you render again the template and include it again ... WTF ?

Comment: @t-n-y : the block is overidden by the contactController's new action ! WTF! Give a clean to your specs?

Comment: so maybe you don't specify it well in your post, but what i see here, is taht you render `contact/new.html.twig` and in that file you call render of that same controller ... don't see any overidde here

Comment: ok i think i understand, it is not the `contact/new.html.twig` you are showing us ?

Comment: @t-n-y I tried in mutiliple ways: I have already tried render **contact/new** to **contact/new.html.twig**. and including the **new.html.twig** to **base.html.twig**. Unfortunatly i have got this error _Variable "contactForm" does not exist._

Comment: you should update your post, we don't understand what templete is it, if it s the new.html.twig , if it s not, then show it !

Comment: @t-n-y   It's is an auto-generated doctrine CRUD. Everything is good within the CRUD. When i have used only the new.html.twig for the contact form purpose. And i have included by overridding my `{% block contact %}{% endblock%}`  The included form doesn't post any data. that's the problem

Comment: If i search on google "update symfony post data" I may find a solution?

Comment: I don't understand anything , you keep telling that you override, fine but you don't explain everything so i can't help you

Comment: @t-n-y : Sir, I leave the override! I said clearly, i want to use my autogenerated CRUD view files( new.html.twig) for my contact form. So i included it. While inserting the new contacted message data, that will be saved in DB table and sendMail function sends a mail at the same it. That's the triel i make.

Comment: @t-n-y : Before adding my sendmail function. I have encouted this problem. The included form doesn't post any data

Comment: @t-n-y Please see my modified source code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like you create a `new Contact()`, but you don't actually set any values in it!

Try something like this!

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $dataArray = $form->getValuesOrWhateverMethod();
    $contact->setWhatever($dataArray['whatever']);
    // etc
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($contact);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Also, you're probably better splitting that if statement like so:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // populate entity and persist
    } else {
        // populate form with whatever WAS valid
        // send form not valid message to view 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand it clearly!  the same method action works when validate the form on this route "site_domain/contact/new". Exceptionally it's not working on my home page.

Comment: I have rendered the form to my homepage by using this `{% block contact %}{{ render(controller('BlogBundle:Contact:new')) }}{% endblock %}`

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you show us the code of `ContactType` ?
2. I would suggest that you can go through https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes again as it shows the example which is something similar to what you want to achieve.
3. It should also be very handy to debug with symfony's dump() function.

Comment: Yes, it's created in my bundle. i add this in my question immediatly

Comment: The ContactType is added